# Should I be concerned that Arabic shows up when I do a google search for maps?

Tags: google

I live in the united states and do not speak arabic at all. Should I be concerned that Arabic script is showing up in one of my searches? Is it possible that a malicious actor who speaks Arabic is changing settings on my machine?
[image]

Comment: This would not be the result of someone changing something on your machine.

Comment: My computer returns the same result. This is likely not a malicious alteration of your computer or Google account and more so a result of Google's search indexing/ranking system.

Comment: VPN in use? when i am behind my vpn, even though it says it is an american city, i occassionaly get foreign language google pages -- not just a result, but entire website version. Lately it's been the text you'd see in middle eastern languages. i've seen all spanish, too. Not all sites do this. Mainly just google from what i experience, and google maps places me in the vpn server's city, too... funny stuff. In fact, i just swapped servers due to this problem and google searched to see if others had the same issue. this is slightly different context, but figured i'd see if it helps your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about. I live in Japan and it throws the same results. I think is good that you did notice the difference (which means you are aware of small changes). Google decided to add some localization to its results for some reason (maybe to show that there is support in that language?). Its indeed strange to me as well, why displaying just a single non-english language (why not Japanese, Korean, Chinese, Russian, etc?)

[image: google maps result]

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe it's a default if you have location services turned off. Do you have location services turned off?

Comment: @user3622268: yes I have location services off.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is if you are sharing your IP with others (large shared internet like a community provided internet with few external IPs) or use VPN, Google may mix other's interests with your search results.